# Fixed-height bxSlider with centered images

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I've got a bxSlider instance that I want to fit into a 800x800 pixel div. However, the viewport has a style attribute setting it to the height of the tallest image, e.g.

```
<div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; 
position: relative; height: 1064px;">
```

This happens even if the tallest image is not the first slide. Is there a way I can control the height of bxSlider with CSS instead? (I need to make it responsive too).

Here's the markup:

```
<ul class="slideshow">
  <li>
    <img src="http://localhost/test/3-1000x673.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>Caption for this image</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://localhost/test/5-1000x1457.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>Another caption for this image</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <img src="http://localhost/test/8-1000x1634.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>The tallest image</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And the bxSlider configuration:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('.slideshow').bxSlider({
        auto: true,
        autoHover: true,
        autoDelay: 1000,
        adaptiveHeight: false,
        mode: 'horizontal'
    });
});
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem and for your case I hope this will solve it :

```
<style>
.slideshow {width: 800px; max-height: 800px; overflow: hidden; }
</style>
```

the max-height and overflow hidden is used to hide second or more images visible during loading.